# Staging Sites: What to push through?

Tags: staging

I have a staging site where I am improving the theme and layout, adding a couple of plugins to add a slide in navigation bar etc. The issue is that on the live site, people are signing and purchasing membership, plus some memberships are expiring etc. Oh and I'm with siteground.

My question is, how do I push through my staging site so that the users' data on the live site persist? Is all user data stored in the same table? When pushing the new site is it possible to only push through the database tables that I have made changes to due to my development, leaving all other tables in tact from the live site?

Comment: Most of the staging utilities I see will replace code and DB - so on sites where user's adding data, like transactions via eCommerce, I only ever push from LIVE to STAGING.  When I've finished testing on my staging site, I download my updated plugins and then replace them on the live site via FTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siteground should be able to tell you if your sites share a DB (or it should be evident from whatever control panel they provide).

That said, it's generally not advisable to mess with the DB of a live site. Make your changes and configure your plugins on stage, then when you're happy, replicate that work on your production site - at a low-traffic time, if necessary.